# Flutter: Error when parsing private key: Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'ASN1Exception'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, rsa, private-key

I was trying to read from my private key file, it can successfully read the file, the problem occurs when it "parse", it seems that the type of each line in the private key file can't be identified.

The code I used to read from the file which contains private key:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart';

final privatePem = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/keys/privateKey.pem');
final privateKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(privatePem) as RSAPrivateKey;
```

The private key file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAYEAuLH+NlYudg5/RMZ8j12ax0IXezsTvLJ+wzoPan2SJe+/YXBipWN7
16vu42gqt9JpD8uvEoE/BHPZuotW1Yh6hRS8U5SGldMJLFhBFG6PZZJf+f1Sn81YnChXGG
...(I skiped the key otherwise it will be too long)
1OWee05wTrCIZzeOt3G+jm1uxjxJAleD7l1e9KbNTSh0VfGJqJSpVS12lyj+xci256lZGp
idJwcxMgJQZ/1NAAAAEHFpc2h1LmxpdUB1dHQuZnIBAg==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The error it displays:

```
flutter: Status Code: 200
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'ASN1Exception'
#0      ASN1Parser._doPrimitive (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:114:9)
#1      ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:51:13)
#2      ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#3      new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#4      ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#5      ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#6      new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#7      ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#8      ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#9      new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#10     ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#11     ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#12     new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#13     ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#14     ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#15     new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#16     ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#17     ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#18     new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#19     ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#20     ASN1Sequence._decodeSeq (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:73:27)
#21     new ASN1Sequence.fromBytes (package:asn1lib/asn1sequence.dart:23:5)
#22     ASN1Parser.nextObject (package:asn1lib/asn1parser.dart:54:26)
#23     RSAKeyParser._parseSequence (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/rsa.dart:244:23)
#24     RSAKeyParser.parse (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/rsa.dart:208:28)
#25     OAuth.getTransferState (package:scambio/fintech_oauth.dart:147:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     InitiatePaymentState.getState (package:scambio/initiate_payment.dart:243:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     InitiatePaymentState.changeData (package:scambio/initiate_payment.dart:312:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Any opinion on how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key has the header and footer of a PEM encoded private key in PKCS#1 format though, but the body seems to belong to that of an OpenSSH key, see e.g. [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/). Possibly your Dart library does not support the OpenSSH format, so a conversion to PKCS#8 or PKCS#1 is necessary. There are tools for this, e.g. ssh-keygen, (after fixing header and footer).

Comment: Seems to be a haphazard way of trying to create a PEM formatted key, by just base 64 encoding bytes and adding a header and footer to it. That only works if the private key is actually a PKCS#1 formatted key - and it is not.